# Principal.IsInRole returns different results for the same WindowsPrincipal, depending on how it is constructed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-identity

I have two ways to construct the same WindowsPrincipal object

Depending on how I construct it, I get different results for `principal.IsInRole()`

Here's my code:

```
var principal1 = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
var principal2 = new WindowsPrincipal(new WindowsIdentity("myName"));

principal1.IsInRole("groupName") :  returns false
principal2.IsInRole("groupName") :  returns true
```

`principal1.Identity.Name` and `principal2.Identity.Name` are the same.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: This link is discussing the exact same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563446/whats-the-difference-between-retrieving-windowsprincipal-from-windowsidentity-a

Answer (score 0):

those 2 principal different from each other. Because you are selecting current user and creating **new** user. If you check principal list from the windowsidentity you will see, principal2 of yours that you created is new and not assigned any group

```
var groupNames1 = from id in WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups
                 select id.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
```

---

```
var groupNames2 = from id in (new WindowsIdentity("myName")).Groups
                 select id.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
```

You will see groupNames1 and groupNames2 different sets of group.

Comment: principal2 does have groups. The same number as principal1, but they are different groups.
Since both principal have the same name, shouldn't they have the same groups?